# General handler for ASP.NET MVC queries

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to create a general handler for all ASP.NET MVC queries. Now I use Application_BeginRequest but there come not only ASP.NET MVC queries.

The one option I see is to create a common base controller and execute my logic in its constructor. But may be there are other options?

Comment: A single, all-purpose action?  Can you elaborate as to _why_ this is necessary?  I'm sure you have your reasons, it just may be helpful in finding a solution to know the true nature of the problem.

Comment: I need to make some kind of redirection specific to localization. So if user requested domain/path I want to redirect to domain/countrycode/path

Comment: idsa, you are correct that one way to go woul;d be via a base controller. however, there are MANY event that can be overriden here. only your requirement will illuminate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered [action filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs)?

Comment: I would prefer a really global solution for all current and future controllers and actions like Application_BeginRequest does

Comment: mvc3 has global action filters

Comment: redsquare, +1 for global action filters

Answer (score 1):

You have to add **ActionFilter** to your controller.

In order to do this you have to create an class inherited from **ActionFilterAttribute**
For example:

```
Public Class CustomFilterAttribute
    Inherits ActionFilterAttribute
End Class
```

Than just apply this attribute to controller:

```
<CustomFilter()> _
Public Class MyController
```

There are 4 methods in ActionFilterAttribute which can be overrided:

```
OnActionExecuted
OnActionExecuting
OnResultExecuted
OnResultExecuting
```

Override them and this code will be executed on each request to methods of your controller

Answer (score 1):

idsa,

you might be able to rustle something up using this kind of approach in a base controller:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
   Lang = requestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString() 
   ?? System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

   ViewData["Lang"] = Lang;

   base.Initialize(requestContext);
   // your custom logic here...
}
```

or on:

```
protected override void Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Execute(requestContext);
    // intercepting code here...
}
```

or:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    // one stage later intercepting code here
}
```

who knows mind you :)